# Can't email Numbers 3.0 or Pages 5.0 documents via Google Mail (Gmail)

Tags: gmail, pages, numbers

When I try to email a Numbers 3.0 or Pages 5.0 document via Google Mail, I receive the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It appears that with the new version of Numbers, Apple changed from using files to using folders that appear as files. Gmail will not allow folders to be emailed.

Google Groups Forum: [Can't send an email with Apple .PAGES attachment document](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/VXFPW-44clg).

Comment: Great find. It will be interesting as an arm-chair pundit to see if people are angry at Apple for "breaking" gmail or Google for rolling out a non-standard, proprietary flavor of IMAP and blocking attachments that would send if you uploaded them through  google chrome to email rather than using Apple's Mail app.

Comment: This is definitely a google problem. The file is automatically zipped before attaching.  Gmail allows some zip files, but does not allow these for some reason.  The only difference in the message source I can find is that the pages document has  x-mac-auto-archive=yes; on the content type, and sending a normal zip file doesn't, but has  x-unix-mode=0644;.  Strangely, zipping the document manually goes through fine, so Gmail must block the x-mac-auto-archive=yes.

Answer (score 0):

Zipping does not help. Gmail looks inside zip files to check for files to block.

This link explains this why putting a blocked file inside a zip file don't work, but it does not explain why a .pages document would be blocked to begin with.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590#